# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Konscious Security Argon2 GetBytes method hangs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

When I run my MVC Application, the Argon2(i) GetBytes method does not complete but instead hangs, for a reason unbeknownst to me. I have set up breakpoints to ensure that the correct parameters are passed to the method, and this is the case, yet when I execute the GetBytes method:

```
var hash = argon2pass.GetBytes(64);
```

The application hangs and the line is never executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in a closed issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/kmaragon/Konscious.Security.Cryptography/issues/11)

**WouterJanson**

I had the same sort of issues, where the code would lock and it would never return a hash.

A simple temporary workaround would be to put the code in a separate method and call it as a task with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning.`

For example:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { hash = YourCryptMethod(password, salt); },TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Wait();
```

I've made a PR (#10) which could fix these problems.